# Android Studio tests not working

Tags: java, android

What should I do when Android Studio for no reason starts reporting "No tests were found" ? The tests worked yesterday. Now I get this random error instead.

The repository is [available online](http://github.com/montao/adventure). My actual test klass looks like:

```
package dev.game.adventure;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AdventureTest {

    private static final String FAKE_STRING = "HELLO WORLD";

    @Mock
    Simulation engine;

    @Mock
    AdventureWorld mWorld;

    @Mock
    Adventure mworld;

    @Mock
    Context aContext;

    @Mock
    FullscreenActivity mActivity;

    @Mock
    Drawable mDrawable;

    @Mock
    Resources mResources;

    @Mock
    Place mPlace;

    @Mock
    AdventureGame ag;



    @Test
    @Ignore
    public void Tedye(){
        //when(mWorld.defaultPlace()).thenReturn(mPlace);
       // myObjectUnderTest.wakeMeAfter(new WalkingPerson(myObjectUnderTest, mWorld, "new", 2, mActivity), 10);
        //String result2 = myObjectUnderTest.getHelloWorldString();
        //assertThat(result2, is(FAKE_STRING));}  createPlace("Heaven", target, R.mipmap.dungeon2);
        //    Adventure a = new Adventure(textview, mactivity, ag);

    }


    @Test
    @Ignore
    public void testd() {
//           Textview scrollable = ''''''''''''(R.id.textView1);

        when(mWorld.defaultPlace()).thenReturn(mPlace);
        Context mCont;

    }




    @Test
    public void adventureWorld() {
       // Simulation myObjecUnderTest = new Simulation();
        Adventure a = new Adventure(new TextView(aContext), mActivity, ag);
        Player p = a.getPlayer();
        p.say("foobar", mActivity);
        p.say("Hello my name is " + a.getPlayer().getMe().name, mActivity);

    }

    @Test
    public void adventureTest () {
            Simulation myObjectUnderTest = new Simulation();
            when(mWorld.defaultPlace()).thenReturn(mPlace);
            myObjectUnderTest.wakeMeAfter(new WalkingPerson(myObjectUnderTest, mWorld, "new", 2, mActivity), 10);
            String result2 = myObjectUnderTest.getHelloWorldString();
            assertThat(result2, is(FAKE_STRING));
        }

        @Test
        public void personTest () {
            Simulation myObjectUnderTest = new Simulation();
            when(mResources.getDrawable(R.mipmap.dungeon)).thenReturn(mDrawable);
            when(mActivity.getResources()).thenReturn(mResources);
            when(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.dungeon)).thenReturn(mDrawable);
            when(mWorld.defaultPlace()).thenReturn(mPlace);
            WalkingPerson myObjectUnderTest2 = new WalkingPerson(myObjectUnderTest, mWorld, "blaha", 2, mActivity);
            String result2 = myObjectUnderTest2.getHelloWorldString();
            myObjectUnderTest2.getThings();
            myObjectUnderTest2.getWorld();
            assertThat(result2, is(FAKE_STRING));
        }

        @Test
        public void trollTest () {
            Simulation myObjectUnderTest = new Simulation();
            AdventureWorld ag;
            when(mResources.getDrawable(R.mipmap.dungeon)).thenReturn(mDrawable);
            when(mActivity.getResources()).thenReturn(mResources);
            when(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.dungeon)).thenReturn(mDrawable);
            when(mWorld.defaultPlace()).thenReturn(mPlace);
            WalkingPerson myObjectUnderTest2 = new Troll(myObjectUnderTest, mWorld, "blaha", mActivity);
            String result2 = myObjectUnderTest2.getHelloWorldString();
            myObjectUnderTest2.getThings();
            AdventureWorld adv = (AdventureWorld) myObjectUnderTest2.getWorld();
            //assertThat(adv.defaultPlace().toString().equals(mWorld.defaultPlace().toString()));
           // assertThat(adv.defaultPlace(), is(FAKE_STRING));
            assertThat(myObjectUnderTest2.getName(), is("Loke"));
            assertThat(adv.messsage, is(FAKE_STRING));
        }

        @Test
        public void cokeTest () {
            when(mWorld.getPlace("Dungeon")).thenReturn(mPlace);
            mWorld.getPlace("Dungeon").addThing(new CocaCola("Ljummen cola"));
            Simulation myObjectUnderTest = new Simulation();
            when(mResources.getDrawable(R.mipmap.dungeon)).thenReturn(mDrawable);
            when(mActivity.getResources()).thenReturn(mResources);
            when(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.dungeon)).thenReturn(mDrawable);
            when(mWorld.defaultPlace()).thenReturn(mPlace);
            WalkingPerson myObjectUnderTest2 = new Troll(myObjectUnderTest, mWorld, "blaha", mActivity);
            String result2 = myObjectUnderTest2.getHelloWorldString();
            myObjectUnderTest2.getThings();
            myObjectUnderTest2.getWorld();
            assertThat(result2, is(FAKE_STRING));
        }

        @Test
        public void testPlace () {
            Simulation myObjectUnderTest = new Simulation();
            when(mResources.getDrawable(R.mipmap.dungeon)).thenReturn(mDrawable);
            mWorld.createPlace("Heaven", mActivity, R.mipmap.dungeon2);
            mWorld.createPlace("Hell", mActivity, R.mipmap.dungeon2);
            mWorld.connect("Heaven", "Hell", "Down", "Up");
            mWorld.randomPlace();

        }

        @Test
        public void useAppContext () throws Exception {
            // Context of the app under test.
            Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
            assertEquals("dev.game.adventure", appContext.getPackageName());
        }
    }
```

[image]

The build log: https://travis-ci.org/montao/adventure

Comment: Add your test code, junit or testng or other?

Comment: You'd probably need to mark that directory as test sources.
Right Click directory > Mark Directory as > Test Sources

Comment: @shinjw But it worked before without me marking a directory. The tests just stopped working.

Comment: Have you updated Android Studio or any dependencies since the tests worked last time? Have you tried to reset the repository to yesterday's state and run the tests? What happens if you attempt to run all tests in `androidTest` directory (right click > run all tests)?

Comment: Does running "File | Invalidate Caches" help?

Comment: I tried everything and nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can't speak to why your tests seem to run before and not now, but i cloned the project and was able to run a test by:

- moving `AdventureTest` from the `src/androidTest` source tree into `src/test`
- commenting out/removing all the Android classes from `AdventureTest`
- adding a simple dummy @Test method (e.g. `assertTrue(false)`)

general rule of thumb:

- if you're going to use Android classes in your tests, then use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/)
- otherwise, use whatever implementation of test runner you please (Mockito in your case)

***EDIT - ADDING SAMPLE ROBOLECTRIC TEST***

Robolectric lets you test your Android code on a plain JVM rather than having to run on Dalvik or otherwise. below is a few lines to get you started, but please refer to http://robolectric.org/ as the framework's offerings are quite expansive.

in `app/build.gradle`, add the following:

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.8.0'
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.5.1"
    ...
}
```

in the below test, `FullScreenActivity` is instantiated and driven through its `create()` method and is then used as a `Context` to create a `TextView`. a bit of your own application code is then called, and then finally an assertion is run against the `TextView` to verify some expected state. no mocks - just what seems to be regular Android classes running on your workstation's JVM.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class AdventureTest {
    ...
    @Test
    public void adventureWorld() {
        mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(FullscreenActivity.class)
                .create()
                .get();

        ag = new AdventureGame(mActivity, null);

        // Simulation myObjecUnderTest = new Simulation();
        final TextView speechTextView = new TextView(mActivity);

        final Adventure adventure = new Adventure(speechTextView, mActivity, ag);

        final Player player = adventure.getPlayer();
        player.say("foobar", mActivity);
        player.say("Hello my name is " + adventure.getPlayer().getMe().name, mActivity);


        assertThat(speechTextView.getText()).containsIgnoringCase("Hello my name is");
    }
    ...
```

i hope that helps!

Comment: What do you mean with "Android classes"? Aren't those the one that Mockito is mocking and therefore I must import them? I don't understand.

Comment: generally speaking, Android classes live under the `android` package namespace. in your case you're using `Context`, `Resources`, `Drawable`, and `TextView`